# Unable to get campaigns data to push to database in google adwords api

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-ads-api

I am facing a couple of issues in figuring out what-is-what, in spite of the humungous documentation I am unable to figure out these issues

1.Which report type should be used to get the campaign level totals. I am trying to get the data in the format of headers
-campaign_id|campaign_name|CLicks|Impressions|Cost|Conversions.
2.I have tried to use "CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" but I get broken up information at a keyword level, but I am trying to pull the data at a campaign level.
3.I also need to push the data to a database. In the API documentation, i get samples which will either print the results on my screen or it will create a file on my machine. is there a way where I can get the data in JSON to push it to the database.
4.I have 7 accounts on my MCC account as of now, the number will increase in the coming days. I don't want to manually hard code the client customer ids into my code as there will be new accounts which will be created. is there a way where I can get the list of client customer ids which are on my MCC ac

I am trying to get this data using python as my code base and adwords api V201710.

Answer (score 1):

1. To retrieve campaign performance data you need to run a *campaign_performance_report*. Follow [this link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report) to view all available columns for Campaign performance report.
2. The [campaign performance report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report) does not include stats aggregated at a keyword level. Are you using AWQL to pull your report?

   Can you paste your code here, I find it odd you are getting keyword level data.

   Run [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201710/basic_operations/get_campaigns_with_awql.py) python example code to get campaign data (you should definitely not be getting keyword level data with this example code).
3. Firstly Google AdWords API only returns report data in the following file formats CSVFOREXCEL, CSV, TSV, XML, GZIPPED_CSV, GZIPPED_XML. Unfortunately JSON is not supported for your use case. I would recommend GZIPPED_CSV and set the following properties to false:
   skipReportHeader
   skipColumnHeader
   skipReportSummary

   This will simply skip all headers, report titles & totals from the report making is very simple to upsert data into a table.
4. It is not possible to enter a MCC ID and expect the API to fetch a report for all client accounts. Each API report request contains the client ID, so therefore you are required to create an array of all client IDs and then iterate through each id. If you are using the client library (recommended) then you can simply set the clientID within the session i.e. session.setClientCustomerId("xxx");

   To automate this use the [ManagedCustomerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201710/ManagedCustomerService) to automatically retrieve all clientIDs then iterate through this therefore you would not need to hard code each ClientID. Google have created a handy python file which returns the account hierarchy including child account ID [(click here)](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201710/account_management/get_account_hierarchy.py).

Lastly I based on your question I assume you attempting to run an ETL process. Google have an [opensource AdWords extractor](https://github.com/googleads/aw-reporting) which I highly recommend.

Comment: thanks a ton for your patience in answering the questions.
1.I did use campain_performance_report, but I was using adgroup_id and keywords in the selector which I was using
3.I used csv.DictReader and json.dumps() in conjunction to achieve the json result which i was using.
4. I was successful in resolvin this issue.
Thanks a ton again for you help.